# Inserting word from a text file into a tree in C

Tags: c, file, binary-search-tree

I have been encountering a weird problem for the past 2 days and I can't get to solve it yet. I am trying to get words from 2 texts files and add those words to a tree. The methods I choose to get the words are refereed here:
[Splitting a text file into words in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317612/splitting-a-text-file-into-words-in-c/37317950?noredirect=1#comment62160755_37317950]).

The function that I use to insert words into a tree is the following:

```
void InsertWord(typosWords Words, char * w)
{
   int error ;
   DataType x ;
   x.word = w ;
   printf(" Trying to insert word : %s \n",x.word );
   Tree_Insert(&(Words->WordsRoot),x, &error) ;
   if (error)
   {
       printf("Error Occured \n");
   }
}
```

As mentioned in the link posted , when I am trying to import the words from a text file into the tree , I am getting "Error Occured". For once again the function:

---

*the text file :*

a

aaah

aaahh

---

```
char this_word[15];
while (fscanf(wordlist, "%14s", this_word) == 1) 
{
   printf("Latest word that was read: '%s'\n", this_word);
   InsertWord(W,this_word);
}
```

But when I am inserting the exact same words with the following way , it works just fine.

```
    for (i = 0 ; i <=2 ; i++)
    {
    if (i==0)
        InsertWord(W,"a");
    if (i==1)
        InsertWord(W,"aaah");
    if (i==2)
        InsertWord(W,"aaahh");
    }
```

That proves the tree's functions works fine  , but I can't understand what's happening then.I am debugging for straight 2 days and still can't figure it. Any ideas ?

Comment: I think we need to see the source code for `Tree_Insert()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read the words using

```
char this_word[15];
while (fscanf(wordlist, "%14s", this_word) == 1) 
{
   printf("Latest word that was read: '%s'\n", this_word);
   InsertWord(W,this_word);
}
```

you are always reusing the same memory buffer for the strings. This means when you do

```
x.word = w ;
```

you are ALWAYS storing the SAME address. And every read redefine ALL already stored words, basically corrupting the data structure.

Try changing the `char this_word[15];` to `char *this_word;` and placing a this_word = malloc(15);`in the beggining of the`while` loop instead, making it allocate a new buffer for each iteration. So looking like

```
char *this_word;
while (fscanf(wordlist, "%14s", this_word) == 1) 
{
   this_word = malloc(15);
   printf("Latest word that was read: '%s'\n", this_word);
   InsertWord(W,this_word);
}
```

As suggested by Michael Walz a strdup(3) also solves the immediate problem.

Of course you will also have do free up the `.word` elements when finished with the tree.

Comment: It would be better if the string is read into the fixed size buffer `this_word` and then using  [`strdup`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) in `InsertWord` like this: `x.word = strdup(w) `.;

Comment: thanks for the answer, i will try this just now !! Let;s hope for the best

Comment: where should i change it ? i did outside of the while and still having the same problem

Comment: Yes, outside the while will make no difference. Fixing that with @MichaelWalz suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem was in the assignment of the strings.Strdup seemed to solve the problem !